# CSS3 animations not working in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, sass

I have some `SASS` rules that are working perfectly on `Chrome` and I am trying to make them work on `Firefox`, too.

I am testing the code on latest `Firefox` versions on `Windows 7` and `Ubuntu 12.04` and it is not working:

- 30.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0
- 30.0

Here are the `SASS` classes that are working on `Chrome` with `Firefox` rules added. Could anyone say what I am missing:

```
.rs-wrapper
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px
    -moz-perspective: 1000px
    perspective: 1000px

.rs-card, .rs-cover, .rs-transition
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d
  transform-style: preserve-3d

rs-flip01
  .rs-front, .rs-back
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden
    backface-visibility: hidden
  .rs-back
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
  &.rs-show .rs-card
    -webkit-animation: rs-flip01 1s ease-in-out forwards
    -moz-animation: rs-flip01 1s ease-in-out forwards
    animation: rs-flip01 1s ease-in-out forwards

@-webkit-keyframes rs-flip01
  0%
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)
  100%
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)

@-moz-keyframes rs-flip01
  0%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)
  100%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)

@keyframes rs-flip01
  0%
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)
  100%
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
```

These are the all styles that are making the animation working on `Chrome`. I must have missed something or done it wrong.

The following line returns `true` on both browsers:

```
Modernizr.csstransforms3d
```

Also, what I can tell is that the functions that I am binding on animation `start` and `end` events are not firing on `Firefox`.

Comment: are you using the compiled version of sass (css) or plain sass in Firefox & chrome?

Comment: @ImranBughio I am using `Ruby on Rails` framework - it is converting the `sass` version to `css` automatically for me.

Comment: Can you post the an example with the resulting CSS on JSFiddle?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I know that this is the best way to get some help but it will be very difficult. I will at least try. Meanwhile I can show you from where I have coppied/downloaded the effects - http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTransitions/index.html

Comment: Well, that doesn't work on FF in the first place...

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Yes it does not. But it is an old example. I have checked all of the user `CSS3` animations and it is said that `Firefiox` supports them already. So, I am trying to make this cross-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/Xf3P6/1/)*

I don't know what your markup is but i have created this demo which also works on Firefox.

**Reason your SCSS not working in Firefox:**
You wrote `transition` at several places where you should have wrote `transform`.

**Example:**

```
/* WRONG */
@-moz-keyframes rs-flip01
  0%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)
  100%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)

/* CORRECT */
@-moz-keyframes rs-flip01
  0%
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)
  100%
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
```

I think you missed to notice this when text-editor suggested the word transition while typing transform -- happens a lot with me :)